# rxjs websocket: ping not being returned

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

Using rxjs and angular 6. 95% of the answers I've seen only use older versions of rxjs.

The server I'm connecting to requires a valid jwt token as a cookie during the connection initiation. Once the server responds with a 101 Switching Protocols, it immediately emits `{ "status": "OK" }`.

The next part of the handshake is for the client (what I'm writing) to send `{ "sessionId": "xxyyzz" }`. The server responds with another `{ "status": "OK" }` and then begins emitting events.

Or at least, it should?

I receive the first `{ "status": "OK" }` message, send the sessionId and userId, and the second `{ "status": "OK" }` comes through.

I am new to rxjs and observables so I'm wondering if my setup is incorrect. If I send a ping, the browser shows the ping frame being sent, but it's not responded to (The implementation server-side works - coworkers connect via android, etc, just fine).

Is `subject.next("ping")` even the right method? I'm just going round in circles and would appreciate any insight.

```
subject: WebSocketSubject<any>;
connectAttempted: boolean;
connected: boolean;

connect(sessionId, userId) {    
        this.subject = webSocket({
            url: `wss://remote.api.server/stream`
        });

        this.subject.subscribe(
            (msg) => {
                if(msg.status && msg.status == "OK" && !this.connectAttempted) {
                    this.subject.next(
                        {
                            sessionId: sessionId,
                            userId: userId,
                            eventClasses: []
                        }
                    );
                    this.connectAttempted = true;
                } else if(msg.status && msg.status == "OK" && !this.connected) {
                    console.log("Handshake completed");
                    this.connected = true;
                    this.subject.next("ping");
                } else if(msg.status && msg.status == "FAIL") {
                    this.connected = false;
                    console.log("FAIL! No longer connected");
                } else {
                    console.log("Something other than status", JSON.stringify(msg))    
                }
            },
            (err) => {
                console.log('error', err)
            },
            () => {
                console.log('complete?')
                this.connected = false;
                this.connectAttempted = false;
            }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your backend but maybe you should stringify the data you want to send. Everything you receive through the subscription gets parsed automatically.

```
this.subject.next(JSON.stringinfy(...));
```

See this page ("Pushing messages to the server"): https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket